# Parsing HTML url jsoup android

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="programList">

            <li class="showing">
                <div class="filterTime"></div>
                <div class="filterGenre"></div>
                <div class="outerSmallPoster">
                    <span class="posterBanner"></span>
                    <a href="/filmdatabase/06-juni/22-jump-street/">
                        <img src="/fileshare/filarkivroot/AuroraKino/Filmer/06%20-%20juni/22%20Jump%20Street/kynoefo11.jpg?width=160" class="smallPoster" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="movieDescr">
                    <a class="movieTitle" href="/filmdatabase/06-juni/22-jump-street/">22 Jump Street</a>

                    <p class="movieDescription">Channing Tatum og Jonah Hill er tilbake i rollene som radarparet Jenko og Schmidt i oppfølgeren til...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="outerMovieDescription">



                    <div class="outerProgramTicketSale">


                        <button type="button" data-frames="underholdning" data-hour="21" href="http://91.207.226.164/ticketweb.php?sign=2&UserCenterID=100007&PaymentType=000&ShowID=484797&PaymentTypeSelection=&ErrorCode=0" target="_blank" onclick="openTicket(100007,484797);return false;" data-usercenterid="100007" data-showid="484797" class="programTime">
                            21:15

                        </button>
                        <span class="theater">Sal 6</span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </li>

</ul>
```

This code is at a URL which I am trying to parse from an android app. To do so, I have written the following code:

```
    protected Hashtable<String, Elements> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Get all the movies from aurorakino and return a list of them
        // to the postexecute method.

        MainActivity.out("Bakgrunn");

        Hashtable<String, Elements> map = new Hashtable<String, Elements>();

        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://fokus.aurorakino.no/billetter-og-program/").get();

            Elements title = doc.select("a.movieTitle");
            Elements desc = doc.select("p.movieDescription");
            Elements image = doc.select("img.smallPoster");

            MainActivity.out(title.size());

            MainActivity.out("Vi er inne i try");

            map.put("title", title);
            map.put("desc", desc);
            map.put("image", image);

            return map;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            MainActivity.out("Noe gikk galt");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This code is in an AsyncTask, and the task is running. I print some debug info from each stage in the asynctask so that I can see if its actually running. And it is.

My problem is that even though the html page has a few links like this:

```
<a href="xxx" class="movieTitle">movie title></a>
```

the code dont manage to find any of them. I print the element size and it says zero.

When i remove the class specification it finds 73 titles.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: When I test it against the same URL and select all `a.movieTitle` I get all the elements. There must be something else that is wrong with your code, since the Jsoup is working just fine!

Comment: You are correct. I dont know why it did not work firsthand. Works now, thanks!

Comment: If your problem is solved, please post your solution as an answer and *accept* it.